# ChartJS - Why is the transition on the first dataset bad?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

So I have react-datepicker to choose the dates of my data, the data that is returned looks like this:

```
{clicks: 6, date: "2022-05-15", link: "instagram"},
{clicks: 5, date: "2022-05-15", link: "google"}...
```

On load and every change in the datePicker, I have this function which sets the data variables, the date will be moment():

```
const onChangeClick = (dates: any) => {
const [start, end] = dates;
setStartDateClick(start);
setEndDateClick(end);

if (start & end) {
  let dates = {
    dateFrom: moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    dateTo: moment(end).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
  }
  _statisticsService.getClickStats(dates).then((response: any) => {
    response.data.map((e: any) => {
      clicksData[e?.link].push(e)
    })

    setInstaDataClick(clicksData['instagram'].map((e: any) => {
      return { clicks: e.clicks, date: moment(e.date) }
    }))
    setFacebookDataClick(clicksData['facebook'].map((e: any) => {
      return { clicks: e.clicks, date: moment(e.date) }
    }))
    setGoogleDataClick(clicksData['google'].map((e: any) => {
      return { clicks: e.clicks, date: moment(e.date) }
    }))
    setTripadvisorDataClick(clicksData['tripadvisor'].map((e: any) => {
      return { clicks: e.clicks, date: moment(e.date) }
    }))
    setWebsiteDataClick(clicksData['website'].map((e: any) => {
      return { clicks: e.clicks, date: moment(e.date) }
    }))
  })
  setLabelsClick(getDaysArray(clicksData[0]?.date, clicksData[clicksData.length - 1].date))

}

};
```

And later I use this values in the datasets:

```
const data = {
labels: labelsClick,
datasets: [
  {
    label: 'Instagram',
    data: instaDataClick,
    borderColor: '#c32aa3',
    backgroundColor: '#c32aa3',
  },
  {
    label: 'Facebook',
    data: facebookDataClick,
    borderColor: '#1877f2',
    backgroundColor: '#1877f2',
  },
  {
    label: 'Google',
    data: googleDataClick,
    borderColor: '#ea4335',
    backgroundColor: '#ea4335',
  },
  {
    label: 'Tripadvisor',
    data: tripadvisorDataClick,
    borderColor: '#34e0a1',
    backgroundColor: '#34e0a1',
  },
  {
    label: 'Website',
    data: websiteDataClick,
    borderColor: '#010101',
    backgroundColor: '#010101',

  },
],
};
```

And at the end this is how I preview the Line chart

```
 <div className='datepicker-container'>
          <DatePicker
            onChange={onChangeClick}
            startDate={startDateClick}
            endDate={endDateClick}
            selectsRange
            placeholderText='Select Date'
            isClearable
          />
 </div>

 <div className='chart'>
          <Line options={options} data={data} />
 </div>
```

The options for this line look like this, x axis is the date and y is the clicks:

```
const options: ChartOptions<'line'> = {
responsive: true,
scales: {
  y: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Date'
    },
    ticks: {
      precision: 0,
    }
  },
  x: {
    type: 'time',
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Date"
    },
    time: {
      unit: 'day',
      stepSize: 1,
      displayFormats: {
        day: "MMM DD"
      }
    }
  },
},
parsing: {
  xAxisKey: 'date',
  yAxisKey: 'clicks',
},
plugins: {
  legend: {
    position: 'top',
  },
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'Click statistics',
  },
},
};
```

And now **THE PROBLEM:**

On first load, the first line in the dataset, in this case Instagram, shows like this:
[image: Instagram Line coming from left]

The instagram line has a different animation, what could be the problem?

[edit]: Changing the animation in options won't affect the instagram line, it will still come from the left, depending on the animation, it will come either slower or faster, but always from left.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who has the same issue in the future, here is the solution:

The problem with my code was that the first state of the instaDataClick variable was an empty array, it should have a date property, because the x axis is the date.

so the variable should look something like this:

```
const initialStartDate = new Date(moment().subtract(10, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
const initialEndDate = new Date(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'))

 const [instaDataClick, setInstaDataClick] = useState(
getDaysArray(initialStartDate.toString(), initialEndDate.toString()).map((e)=>{
  return {clicks: null, date: e}
})
)
```

the function getDaysArray:

```
const getDaysArray = function (start: any, end: any) {
for (var arr = [], dt = new Date(start); dt <= new Date(end); dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1)) {
  arr.push(new Date(dt).toString().substr(4, 6));
}
return arr;
};
```

And by doing this, we're setting the initial position of the line.